# What is the difference of Jetty Server and Embedding Jetty in my Application

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, embedded-jetty

I am building right now a Web Application, and generating a .war file.

How can I embed Jetty into it, so that this war can be a stand-alone application?

And that brings me to the key question, how is this different from deploying this war file into a Jetty Server?

Am I confusing something? Should I actually build a regular Java - jar -application, and start the server from a Main method, adding the Servlet and Handlers there?

> My goal is to have a stand-alone java application, using a WebSocket Servlet, and I am using Jetty 8

Comment: The difference is the same as between moving your bed by putting it in a trailer, or moving your bed by putting wheels and a motor on it. For instructions on how to use embedded jetty, read the documentation.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18428968/how-to-deploy-war-with-embedded-jetty-server/18429414#18429414

Comment: The other two comments have hit the nail on the head but I wanted to remind you that Jetty 8 is EOL and you should probably consider upgrading.

Comment: Jetty can be run in embedded mode. It means that it is not necessary to build a WAR file and deploy it in a standalone Jetty server.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a self-executing WAR that has embedded-jetty in it.

The jetty project maintains such a project at

https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-live-war